# What options does my hero have for burning down (or otherwise destroying) her house using means readily available?

Tags: construction, fire

My hero is a young female adult who's fascinated with old houses, so she bought one. The date is just "very old" and it is recognized as an historic building.  Assume this is in the United States using wooden construction with some repairs, but otherwise it's generally just an intact old building.

For reasons, she needs to destroy the house. Burning it down seems like it would be easiest, though other methods of destruction are also an option.

The catch is that, at least with the current plot, she is unable to leave the house to get supplies, much less higher a demolition company.

I've looked over ways that people accidentally burn their house down, and they all seem to have a bit too much element of "luck" to get a good burn going -- a partial burn is not acceptable.

What options does she have?

Comment: Do you realize the implications of asking advice on how to burn down a house?

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica Honestly hadn't thought it through. I'm definitely not planning anything in real life!

Comment: I suggest doing some research about arson or fire hazards then asking how believable a scenario is , as it stands this is both too story based and not a good question for this site. If the best answer for your question is just a long list it needs more focus.

Answer (score 2):

Most old houses are fire death traps anyway. Old furniture is extremely flammable, old gas lines were easy to damage and ignite, and old carpets are basically petrol. I renovated a place where the insulation was dry crumpled newspaper - they're basically fire bombs ready to go.

Your house was retrofitted with electric outlets in the roaring 20s. The installation was done on the cheap but is compliant with the laws at the time it was installed. 100 years have passed since.

- Cut power.
- Remove fuse wire from switch box.
- put forks in all the electrical outlets.
- put penny in the fuse box between the connections.
- switch power back on.

Note if you are trying this in real life you wont be able to remove the penny from the fuse box or forks from the outlets - theres a good chance they'll fuse together. Arson investigation will be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Your totally fictional character should crumble a bag of potato chips and make a line from the toaster to the curtains and other flammable stuff. Chips burn very well and leave no trace. If it's an old house, the fire department will assume it was faulty wiring. Bonus damage against ghosts if you identify a load bearing wall and cause the roof to cave in quickly.